# How to take the current url into a php variable?

Tags: php

I want to take the url generated from a dynamic web in to a php variable
Suppose there is one adress in url

> www.example.com/new/id=2

I want to take the parts new/id=2 in to a php variable.

same time that variable is able to take new/id=2&title=ARTICLE
 from

> www.example.com/new/id=2&title=ARTICLE

Is there any tricks which can do that job?.

Comment: Please be more specific when asking questions and research on google

Comment: As a general comment: Depending on the usage this can be dangerous, because attackers could inject arbitrary code (HTML/JavaScript). E.g. by appending ```?"><script>alert("evil");</script><"``` or ```/"><script>alert("evil");</script><"``` (directly after the .php ending).

Comment: @KhanShahrukh pls do one thing Avoid the comment " 
Please be more specific when asking questions and research on google " Cause lot are telling the same comment And try somthing diffrent!.

Comment: @Neenu Allrite I will make sure of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$full_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Comment: This does not work for https or different ports, also it does not contain the query string

Answer (score 0):

look at $_SERVER array

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$_SERVER` globals to get this info. `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` should give you `new/id=2` and the full (GET) request URI.

ETA: My bad. MrTux is right... you need to concatenate `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` to get the URI and the query. So try this:

```
$uri_query = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
```

Comment: For a more complete implementation that solves MrTux's valid comment on user3659034's answer, see [this cheatsheet](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php).

Comment: You still might need to add a "?" before ```.$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]```.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parse_url function of php.

```
$url = '//www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';

$query=parse_url($url));

var_dump($query);
```

The above example will output

```
array(3) {
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(5) "/path"
  ["query"]=>
  string(17) "googleguy=googley"
}
```

That means you will get your required value at $query["query"]

Answer (score 0):

When you use `print_r($_SERVER);`, you get a peak into all the server details, including the page referrer, in `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.